# R: Pairwise Matrix Manipulation & Variable Construction with Many Groups

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, large-data

I'm starting with data of scores at the "group-person" level as follows:

```
group_id person_id  score
1        1          3
1        2          1
1        3          5
2        1          3
2        2          3
2        3          6
```

The goal is to generate data on person-person pairs that looks like the following:

```
person_id1 person_id2  sumsquarederror
1          2           4
1          3           13
2          3           25
```

where the "sumsquarederror" variable is defined as the sum across all groups of the squared differences in score values for each possible pair of persons. In mathspeak, this variable would be defined like: for persons i=1 and i=2 and groups j=(1,...,J)

```
sumsquarederror(i=1,i=2) = sum_j (( score(i=1) - score(i=2) )^2)
```

Building this data is trivial with small numbers of groups and persons, but I have roughly 1,000 groups and 150,000 persons, so creating matrices/dataframes for all combinations possible quickly becomes computationally burdensome (=150K by 150K by 1K, before collapsing to the sumsquarederror variable)

I'm guessing there might be some linear algebra approaches or regression-type ideas, but am stumped. Any tips or tricks or useful packages would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain why group `1 3 = 13`? and group `2 3 = 25`?

Comment: For group(1,3), the sumsquarederror = (3-5)^2 + (3-6)^2 = 13. 
For group(2,3), the sumsquarederror = (1-5)^2 + (3-6)^2 = 25.